# Errors in building Opencv with extra modules in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.1

I have configured and generated opencv 3.2 with extra modules on CMAKE successfully using a 32-bit compiler of Visual Studio 2015 (vs14). However, when building this project in Visual Studio I get several errors. Below, you could find: small sample of the errors, the CMake ouput

Error Sample

> LNK1120 50 unresolved externals opencv_hdf 
>   C:\OpenCV3_02_Custom\build\bin\Debug\opencv_hdf320d.dll 1    LNK1112
>   module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' 
>   opencv_python3 
>   C:\OpenCV3_02_Custom\build\modules\python3\python35.lib(python35.dll) 
>   1

CMake Ouput:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0 =====================================

Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/OpenCV3_Custom/source/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2017-02-28T15:51:02Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.14393 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.7.1
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.23506.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast    /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast    /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:X86  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 vfw32 C:/Users/Ibrahim/Anaconda3/Library/lib/hdf5.lib
    3rdparty dependencies:       zlib libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf libprotobuf

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann hdf imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow phase_unwrapping stitching structured_light python3
    Disabled:                    world contrib_world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 viz cnn_3dobj cvv freetype matlab sfm

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.24)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO
    GDCM:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 3.1.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
         at:                     C:/OpenCV3_02_Custom/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
    Include path:                C:/OpenCV3_02_Custom/source/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Users/Ibrahim/Anaconda3/python.exe (ver 3.5.2)
    Libraries:                   C:/Users/Ibrahim/Anaconda3/libs/python35.lib (ver 3.5.2)
    numpy:                       C:/Users/Ibrahim/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.1)
    packages path:               C:/Users/Ibrahim/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/Ibrahim/Anaconda3/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:
    mex:                         C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/mex.bat
    Compiler/generator:          Not working (bindings will not be generated)

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       NO
    Performance tests:           NO
    C/C++ Examples:              YES

  Install path:                  C:/OpenCV3_02_Custom/build/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              C:/OpenCV3_02_Custom/build
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
Generating done
```

Comment: Try unselect **BUILD_opencv_hdf** in CMake GUI, then build again.

Comment: why `[C++Builder]` tag when you are using visual studio?  why `[opencv 3.1]` tag when you are building `3.2` ?

Comment: Additonally, on my CMake output, both _Version control:_ and _Version control (extra):_ showed _3.2.0_.